# Change the CSV format from comma into semicolon when exporting data into local machine from Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

Im located in europe and our machine read semi colon data and I was wondering is there is a way to adapt the instance of Snowflake to export data into semicolon ?
or if possible to add format as needed to the instance ?

many thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Try using the FIELD_DELIMITER parameter. This is covered in the documentation https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/copy-into-location.html#type-csv